# How to convert a union of column pair values into a linear table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

**The problem**

We have a table of duplicate customer numbers:

```
A varchar(16) NOT NULL,
B varchar(16) NOT NULL
```

These columns started off as Old and New (Delete and Retain), but devolved to where neither is preferred. The columns really are just "A" and "B" -- two numbers for the same customer, in any order.

Furthermore, the table can have an arbitrary number of pairs for the same customer. You might see rows like

```
a,b
b,c
```

meaning a,b,c are all for the same customer. You might also see rows like

```
a,b
b,a
c,a
```

meaning a,b,c are all the same customer.

It's *not* a clean acyclic representation like "old" and "new" values. The list of customer IDs for a customer is represented in this table in chunks of one or more rows, where the only connection is that the value for A or B column in one row might show up in the A or B column in some other row. My mission is to tie them all together into the list for each customer.

I want to convert this mess to something like

```
MasterKey int NOT NULL,
CustNum varchar(16) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
PRIMARY KEY( MasterKey, CustNum )
```

The one or more numbers for a customer would share the MasterKey in this table. As the UNIQUE constraint says, a given CustNum can't appear more than once.

So for example, rows like this from the original

```
1a,1b
1b,1c
2a,2b
2b,2c
2d,2a
...
```

should end up as rows like this in the new table

```
1 1a
1 1b
1 1c
2 2a
2 2b
2 2c
2 2d
...
```

Edit: The values above are just to make the pattern clear. The actual customer number values are arbitrary `varchar`s.

**My attempted solutions**

This feels like a job for recursion and therefore a CTE. But the potentially cyclic nature of the source data makes it hard for me to get the anchor case. I've tried to pre-clean it into more of an acyclic form, but I still can't seem to get this right.

I'm also stubbornly trying to do this as a set-based SQL operation, instead of resorting to a cursor and loop. But maybe that's not possible.

I've spent a good 8 hours pondering this and trying different approaches but it keeps slipping away. Any ideas or suggestions on the correct approach, or even some example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to do something I haven't done before, and post an answer to
my own question. I need to give huge thanks to both Beth and JBrooks
for moving me in the right direction. I *really* wanted to solve this
in a set-based, declarative way. And maybe that's still possible using
a CTE and recursion. But once I surrendered and said it's OK for it to
be imperative and iterative, it was much easier to do it.

Anyway, given this target table from my question:

```
CREATE TABLE UniqueCustomers
(
    uid     int NOT NULL,
    gpid    varchar(16) NOT NULL UNIQUE, -- Important: UNIQUE to disallow duplicates
    PRIMARY KEY( uid, gpid ) -- Important: Disallow duplicates
)
```

I came up with the following stored procedure. It can be called when
new dupes are reported, one by one. It can also be called in a loop
over the legacy table that stores the dupes as pairs in a random
order.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ReportDuplicateCustomerIDs
(
    @id1 varchar(16),
    @id2 varchar(16)
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @id1 <> @id2
    BEGIN
        -- Retrieve the uid (if any) for each of the ids
        DECLARE @uid1 int
        SELECT @uid1 = NULL
        SELECT @uid1 = uid FROM UniqueCustomers WHERE gpid = @id1

        DECLARE @uid2 int
        SELECT @uid2 = NULL
        SELECT @uid2 = uid FROM UniqueCustomers WHERE gpid = @id2

        -- If we've seen NEITHER of the id's yet
        IF @uid1 IS NULL AND @uid2 IS NULL
        BEGIN
            -- Add both of them using a brand-new uid
            DECLARE @uidNew int
            SELECT @uidNew = Max(uid) + 1 FROM UniqueCustomers
            IF @uidNew IS NULL
                SET @uidNew = 0
            INSERT INTO UniqueCustomers VALUES( @uidNew, @id1 )
            INSERT INTO UniqueCustomers VALUES( @uidNew, @id2 )
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            -- If we've seen BOTH id's already
            IF @uid1 IS NOT NULL AND @uid2 IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                -- If this pair bridges two existing chains.
                IF @uid1 <> @uid2
                BEGIN
                    -- Update everything using uid2 to use uid1 instead.
                    -- Consolidates the two dupe chains into one.
                    UPDATE UniqueCustomers SET uid = @uid1 WHERE uid = @uid2
                END
                -- ELSE nothing to do
            END
            ELSE
                -- If we've seen only id1, then insert id2 using
                -- the same uid that id1 is already using
                IF @uid1 IS NOT NULL
                    INSERT INTO UniqueCustomers VALUES( @uid1, @id2 )
                -- If we've seen only id2, then insert id1 using
                -- the same uid that id2 is already using
                ELSE -- @uid2 IS NOT NULL
                    INSERT INTO UniqueCustomers VALUES( @uid2, @id1 )
        END
    END
END
GO
```

Comment: I gave up-votes to the two answers the helped me, but I accepted my own answer as it's the most correct and complete. I feel weird doing that, but from the FAQ that seems to be what I ought to do. Thanks again to Beth and JBrooks!

Answer (score 1):

given input data:

```
a,b
b,c
d,e
e,f
g,d
```

I'd add two new tables, one with the pk values, and one with pk and duplicate values in a one-to-many relationship with the pks, like this:

```
pk
a
b
c
d
e
f
g


pk dup
a   b   
b   a
b   c
c   b   
d   e
e   d
e   f
f   e   
g   d
d   g
```

rows in the pk/dup table are populated by your input file with the pks and duplicates inserting both in (pk,dup) sequence and in (dup,pk) sequence.

this gets you your first set of relationships between keys and duplicates, but you'd need to iterate through this set again to get the indirect relationships, like 'c is a duplicate of a'

you can get those relationships by self-joining the pk/dup table on pkdup1.dup = pkdup2.pk.  this joins row (a,b) with rows (b,a) and (b,c) allowing you to identify the relationship (a,c).  it will also pick up (d,f) (f,d) (g,e).  you'd need to repeat the iteration to pick up (g,f)

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to do some looping.  Here I look at 1 row at a time to make sure I get all of the chained values belonging to a single masterkey.

```
while (1=1)
begin

    -- get the next key that is not inserted yet as MasterKey or key
    select top 1 @masterKey = a
    from myTable 
    where not exists (select 1
        from #temp
        where #temp.MasterKey = myTable.a
        or #temp.Key = myTable.a)

    if(@masterKey is null) -- out of a's so now work the b's
        select top 1 @masterKey = b
        from myTable 
        where not exists (select 1
            from #temp
            where #temp.MasterKey = myTable.b
            or #temp.Key = myTable.b)

    if(@masterKey is null) -- totally done.
        break

    insert into #temp
    (masterKey, key)
    values(@masterKey, @masterKey)


    while (1=1) -- now insert anything new with this masterKey in a
    begin
        insert into #temp
        select top 1 @masterKey, myTable.b
        from myTable
        where myTable.a = @masterKey
        not exists (select 1
        from #temp
        where #temp.MasterKey = myTable.b
        or #temp.Key = myTable.b))

        if @@rowcount < 1
            break
    end 


    while (1=1) -- now insert anything with this masterKey in b
    begin
        insert into #temp
        select top 1 @masterKey, myTable.a
        from myTable
        where myTable.b = @masterKey
        not exists (select 1
        from #temp
        where #temp.MasterKey = myTable.a
        or #temp.Key = myTable.a))

        if @@rowcount < 1
            break

    end 

end
```

You would actually have to wrap the 2 insert sections into another loop to make sure it is exhausted before getting the next masterKey, but you get the idea.

Comment: This seems promising, but I don't follow what you're doing with the final two insert statements. In both cases, the `where myTable.x = @masterKey` is followed by `not exists ...` with no glue in between. I wondered if you meant to put `AND` there, but that doesn't seem to be correct? And there's an extra closing paren. Sorry if I'm being dense.

Comment: No, you are right - there should be an AND between the two. And the closing paren is extra, but I wasn't giving you 100% syntax, more of a  way to solve this problem.

Comment: OK I understand. (I definitely wasn't expecting you to write all the code for me. :)  I did want to make sure I grokked your idea.)  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job for union to me. The code below assumes that you can't have 1a, 2b in the same record.

create table #temp (a varchar(10), b varchar (10))

```
insert into #temp
values ('1a', '1b')
,('1b', '1c')
,('2a', '2b')
,('2b', '2c')
,('2d', '2a')

select * from #temp

select a, b, left (a, 1) as id into #temp2 from #temp

select id, a from #temp2 
union 
select id, b from #temp2
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, but I used '1a', '1b', etc. in the examples to make the desired pattern clearer. If the actual data already had such a pattern, this would be easier. :)  Instead the actual values will be arbitrary `varchar`s like 'FOO12', 'BAR666', 'GURGLE721'. So unfortunately we can't get the `MasterKey` value from the values using `Left()`.

Answer (score 0):

What is the pattern to find the key?  If it is just the first number in the string then this would pull it out:

```
select substring('FOO12',patindex('%[0-9]%','FOO12'),100)
```

If it starts with the number than this would pull it out:

```
select substring('12FOO',1,patindex('%[A-Z]%','12FOO')-1)
```

Both return 12.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon some sample data in a comment, I think this should do the trick?

```
CREATE TABLE #sample
(A NVARCHAR(50)
,B NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #sample VALUES('FOO12','12DEF')
INSERT INTO #sample VALUES('12GHJ','12ABC')
INSERT INTO #sample VALUES('GURGLE721','GURGLZ721')
INSERT INTO #sample VALUES('word21','book721')
INSERT INTO #sample VALUES('orange21','apple21')

;WITH CTE as
(
SELECT A
,PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z]%',A) as text_start
,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',A) as num_start
FROM #sample
UNION ALL
SELECT B
,PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z]%',B) as text_start
,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',B) as num_start
FROM #sample
)
,cte2 AS
(
SELECT
*
,CASE WHEN text_start > num_start --Letters after numbers
    THEN SUBSTRING(A,text_start - num_start + 1,99999)
    WHEN text_start = 1 --Letters at start of string
    THEN SUBSTRING(A,1,num_start - 1)
    END AS letters
,CASE WHEN num_start > text_start --Numbers after letters
    THEN SUBSTRING(A,num_start - text_start + 1,99999)
    WHEN num_start = 1 --Numbers at start of string
    THEN SUBSTRING(A,1,text_start- 1)
    END AS numbers
FROM cte
)
SELECT DISTINCT
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY numbers ASC) as group_num
,numbers + letters as cust_details
FROM cte2
ORDER BY numbers + letters asc
```